# Is it possible to create 2D array in g1ant?

Tags: automation, rpa, g1ant

I have worked on lists in g1ant but lists are 1D array, now I want to work on 2D array but I don't know how to do that it g1ant. Is there any way of doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the current state of G1ANT, it is not possible to create a 2D array as a g1ant structure. Although you can use C# snippets in which it is possible to create 2D arrays and operate on them.